# CSS transitions - I need an explanation

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I was trying to move some elements around with transition in CSS. I made it work fine by adding a separate selector for each element I want to transition, but it doesn't work when I use one selector for all (they end up in the same place anyway). Can someone please explain why it doesn't work like this?

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
 }

 .block {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 }

 .part1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 0.2;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
 }

 .part {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 0.2;
  position: absolute;
  transition: top 2s ease-in, left 2s ease-in, right 2s ease-in;
 }

 .block .part:nth-child(2) {
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
 }

 .block .part:nth-child(3) {
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
 }

 .block .part:nth-child(4) {
  top: 0;
  right: 200px;
 }

 .block .part:last-child {
  top: 100px;
  right: 100px;
 }

 .block .part1:hover ~ .part {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
 }
```

```html
<span class="block">
  <span class="part1">O</span>
  <span class="part">O</span>
  <span class="part">O</span>
  <span class="part">O</span>
  <span class="part">O</span>
</span>
```

As you can see, the left property doesn't transition for the fourth and fifth element.

Here's the working snippet:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
 }

 .block {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 }

 .part1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 0.2;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
 }

 .part {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 0.2;
  position: absolute;
  transition: top 2s ease-in, left 2s ease-in, right 2s ease-in;
 }

 .block .part:nth-child(2) {
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
 }

 .block .part:nth-child(3) {
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
 }

 .block .part:nth-child(4) {
  top: 0;
  right: 200px;
 }

 .block .part:last-child {
  top: 100px;
  right: 100px;
 }

 .block .part1:hover ~ .part:nth-child(2) {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
 }

 .block .part1:hover ~ .part:nth-child(3) {
  left: 0;
 }

 .block .part1:hover ~ .part:nth-child(4) {
  right: 0;
 }

 .block .part1:hover ~ .part:last-child {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
 }
```

```html
<span class="block">
  <span class="part1">O</span>
  <span class="part">O</span>
  <span class="part">O</span>
  <span class="part">O</span>
  <span class="part">O</span>
 </span>
```

Why does this happen? I couldn't find the answer in documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because when you share the same `:hover` rule, you're setting `left: 0` on your fourth and fifth elements, so they're going to get positionated accordingly to their parent which is relative (`.block`) then there's no room for them to animate as you desire. When you use a separate selector, `left` remains at it's default value of `auto` so then `right` correctly animates on these two elements.

If you do not specify `left` or `right` their default value is `auto`, not `0`. C[heck MDN docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/left)

Comment: I thought that the transition from auto to 0 should be animated too. 'Guess I was wrong... Tnx @Juan

Answer (score 1):

Although @Juan already answered, You may consider using translate prop instead of absolute position top left.
Here is the article about:
http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

.block {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.part1 {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 0.2;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.part {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 0.2;
    position: absolute;
display:block;
    transition: all 2s linear;
}

.block .part:nth-child(2) {
top:0;
left:0;

transform:translate(100px,100px);
}

.block .part:nth-child(3) {
top:0;
left:0;
transform:translate(200px,0);
}

.block .part:nth-child(4) {
top:0;
left:0;
transform:translate(-200px,0);

}

.block .part:last-child {
top:0;
left:0;
transform:translate(-100px,100px);

}

.block .part1:hover ~ .part {
    transform: translate(0,0);
}
```

Comment: Tnx, I'll read the post you shared. I was going to use translate as a last resort thinking it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I presume that in this case it doesn't really matter. Just wanted you to know the opportunity and pros of using it for next case.